# Remove the product category module block from the Woocommerce product page

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to remove this block:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqXzR.jpg

this is a category block on the product page overview. I want to remove this block but I cannot seem to work it out.

I find a couple of "solutions" on internet but it is not working for me. I get an error 500 and if I check the logs it displays this:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'add_filter' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)
```

This is the solutions i found:

https://www.engagewp.com/remove-categories-woocommerce-product-category-widget/

https://wpbeaches.com/removing-the-product-meta-categories-in-a-product-page-woocommerce/

https://www.engagewp.com/remove-categories-woocommerce-product-category-widget/

Does anyone know how to achieve this?